# Index versions(historical) data

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, search, indexing, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table  storing all the old versions for item in DynamoDB. Is there a way to index the versions data using search engine or other things so that I can do something gracefully for the following scenarios:

Use case 1:
Search for current items that match a specific query with sorting and pagination and get their historical data for a date range (Between January and June, what were the statuses of those items each month?). This would ideally be able to happen in one query.

Use case 2:
Find differences for a field based on the version history.
eg. Find all items whose field changed from 'A' to 'B'

Current state:
Use case 1:
  1.Get all the items matching query first.
  2.For each item ,issue a separate query to get all the versions for that 
  item. 
  3.Do a lot of in-memory filter operations in back end, and get the data 
  within data range.
Use case 2:
   not supported now

Comment: could you post the code and be more specific on the error?

Comment: It's not an error , i am asking if there is a better solution to this question. Our versions data contain modified time, id(different versions for same item share the same id),  given a list of items(ids) can we get all item's status for 2013-01-01T00:00:00Z back using one query?